# Javascript DOM-0 IIFE

Tags: javascript, iife

i'm new at javascript and didn't understand why function declared in Immediately-invoked function expression doesn't work with DOM-0 .
i'm pretty sure it has something to do with variable scope

//HTML CODE

```
<div onclick="test()">some Text</div>
```

//JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
(function(){

  function test(){
      alert('Thank u Stackoverflow');
     }

})()
```

Comment: there is no global test() for the onclick to see; it's a private variable of the IIFE program space that's dead and gone and unreachable from global scope. if you added `window.test=test;` to the bottom of the IIFE, then the element click event can see the published global. bottom line: you can't include html inline event handlers in closure, but, from inside the IIFE, you can use something like `theDiv.addEventListener("click", test);`  or even the old-school `theDiv.onclick=test;` to subscribe the function instead of trying to use a hard-coded inline event attribute.

Comment: Then why you read everywhere in the web that you must englobe your entire javascript script between IIFE ( to spare it with global var) when you can't access function you declare in

Comment: the same folks "everywhere in the web" say you must not use inline event attribute. you can also publish the values you need at the end of the IIFE so that only the parts you explicitly specify are global, instead of all the guts. you can also create a single global object, often referred to by laymen as a namespace, module, object or class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "test" function is in local scope, see about [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

You can expose this function by creating a module., see about [Javascript Modules](http://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html)

Looks like:

```
<div onclick="MyModule.test()">some Text</div>
```

and

```
var MyModule = (function() {
  function test(){
      alert('Thank u Stackoverflow');
  };

  return {
      test: test
  };
})();
```

Just a tip: Never prefer add javascript events directly in html, use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) or [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/), or another library.